# What are the risks to deploying my nodejs app on a web server like siteground as opposed to an internal server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

I have just built a nodejs app (with HTML/JavaScript/css) to handle (among other things) workflow management for my business. I am currently running it on a local computer on the network so it is accessible to all the staff who connected to office WiFi.

So that staff can access the system from outside the office I’m considering grabbing a cheap URL and deploying it on a web server (siteground specifically because I have a reseller account there). However because this is the first web app I’ve built from the ground up I just know there are going to be security vulnerabilities and the like in my coding.

The kind of data that is included in the MongoDB database is fairly basic, just customer/supplier contact information and product information.

How dangerous is it for me to do this, is it something I should worry about or should I be okay? I don’t plan to have it indexed by search engines, it’s only for staff use so I don’t need customers to be able to find it.

Appreciate any insight from people who have been doing this longer than I have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes there are privacy laws, speak to a professional about this and perhaps contact a programmer. One thing if developing another if you're already maintaining an active database. Policies would need to change/etc. That'd be step one perhaps?

Comment: Do you have a login system?

Comment: Thanks @blanknamefornow I'll take that on board, It is a currently existing active database. The only difference would be that it's being stored on a web server instead of an internal server on one of the companies computers. The database information is also currently being stored on MYOB (which is online) and Mailjet (for marketing purposes). Not sure if that makes a difference but will definitely seek professional advice before proceeding.

Comment: @slebetman I have a login system for an older version I built that I'm planning use if I go online. Haven't used logins for the current internal version though because it's only accessible inside the network and isn't super necessary. If I end up taking it online I'll just combine the login system I built with this version.

Comment: If you have a login system then just protect your website using https (you can get free certificates from letsencrypt - you only need a domain name). That's what all websites do to protect themselves. To check if your site can be exploited run something like mongomap against it to try to find weaknesses. Try both a non-logged-in user and a logged-in user.

Comment: Apart from mongomap you can also run generic vulnerability scanners on your website. There are several online scanners - some are free or have a free tier. There are also software you can install on your PC to scan your website. I usually use Nagios to do automatic pentesting but there are other tools as well

Comment: Unfortunately you need to rely on more than just those particular defenses, HTTPS and as well and auth(login) to obtain session is not securing it fully or reputable these days. Many will proxy their networks, block ports like SSH to all but one specific port. ICMP gets turned off, TLS gets forced no exceptions (no downgrading). It goes on and on, and for data-base limiting the firewall to that of the direct IP of the server so not bot can accidentally ping it and tamper with it.

Comment: I'd not take this lightly, one of the biggest hits on a site is the software/code leaking. Often times I see developers becoming victims to tunneled attacks, which allows an attacker to trick your server into revealing data it shouldn't have and this usually has major consequences. Developer generally has no idea this is happening before their eyes and when they do catch it it's likely days late and your update won't be for another few more days! So be safe when handling data and talk to a professional get the best suitable option for your needs if handling large user-sets. :)